# Volley ProgressDialog stuck/freeze at the time of get huge amount of data

Tags: android, android-volley

Here is my code:

```
private void downloadSupplyTownData(final int townId2) {

    /*******************
     * Using Volley
     *******************/
    // Post params to be sent to the server
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("ID",townId2);
   CustomDialogClass.showProgressDialog(context,true); 


    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Consts.baseUrl+Consts.townSupplyUrl, new JSONObject(params),
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       totalConsumerRecords =   Integer.parseInt(response.getString("TotalConsumerRecords").trim());
                       if(totalConsumerRecords>0)
                       {                               
                           /**For -----**/
                           JSONArray dtrArray   =   response.getJSONArray("xxx");
                           for(int i=0;i<dtrArray.length();i++)
                           {
                               JSONObject   dtrObj  =   dtrArray.getJSONObject(i);
                               supplyId1        =   Integer.parseInt(dtrObj.getString("SI"));
                               dtrId            =   Integer.parseInt(dtrObj.getString("DI"));
                               dtrImgUrl        =   dtrObj.getString("DIMG");
                               dtrCode          =   dtrObj.getString("DC");
                               assetPCode       =   dtrObj.getString("APC");
                               meterSN          =   dtrObj.getString("MSN");
                               System.out.println(dtrId);
                               db.addDtrInfo(new DTRBeanClass(dtrId,supplyId1,dtrCode,dtrImgUrl,assetPCode,meterSN));
                           }

                           /**For ----**/
                           JSONArray poleArray  =   response.getJSONArray("Pole");
                           for(int i=0;i<poleArray.length();i++)
                           {
                               JSONObject   poleObj =   poleArray.getJSONObject(i);
                               poleId           =   Integer.parseInt(poleObj.getString("PI"));
                               dtrId1           =   Integer.parseInt(poleObj.getString("DI"));
                               consumerCount    =   Integer.parseInt(poleObj.getString("ACA"));
                               poleImgUrl       =   poleObj.getString("PIMG");
                               poleCode         =   poleObj.getString("PC");
                               surveyerRemarks  =   poleObj.getString("RMS");
                               System.out.println(poleId);
                               db.addPoleInfo(new PoleBeanClass(poleId,dtrId1,poleCode,poleImgUrl,consumerCount,surveyerRemarks));
                           }

                           /**For ----**/
                           JSONArray consumerArray  =   response.getJSONArray("Supply");
                           for(int i=0;i<consumerArray.length();i++)
                           {
                               JSONObject   supplyObj   =   consumerArray.getJSONObject(i);
                               supplyId     =   Integer.parseInt(supplyObj.getString("SI"));
                               supplyTownId =   Integer.parseInt(supplyObj.getString("TI"));
                               supplyName   =   supplyObj.getString("SN");
                               System.out.println(supplyId);
                               db.addSupplierInfo(new SupplierChainBeanClass(supplyId,supplyTownId,supplyName));
                           }

                           CustomDialogClass.showProgressDialog(context,false);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           CustomDialogClass.showProgressDialog(context,false);
                       }

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }                                                          
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                   VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                   Log.d("Eroor", ""+networkResponse);
                   CustomDialogClass.showProgressDialog(context,false);
               }
           });

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    NameApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Here show and hide ProgressDialog by `CustomDialogClass.showProgressDialog(context,true);`

Progress dialog spin first 2-3 seconds and then stuck. Please help me out to handle this.

**EDIT**

/**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        downloadSupplyTownData(townId);

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {            
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }

}
```

And from view call the AsynchTask `new DownloadFileFromURL().execute();`

Comment: what `downloadConsumerData` method doing ?

Comment: It's another method , after complete this it will call. I will remove this. Please wait.

Comment: After removing `downloadConsumerData` method then what happing still Progress dialog stuck?

Comment: probably issue is occuring becuase `onResponse` run on Main UI Thread. so do on test by commenting all code inside `onResponse` and just add on Log to check method is executed or not and call `CustomDialogClass.showProgressDialog(context,false);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK so I will need to different class for parsing? Because I have been already call the method by declaring another thread. Like new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     downloadSupplyTownData(townId2);
        }
      });
    }
  }).start(); But still the problem remains.

Comment: if after removing parsing related code progress bar not stuck then use AsyncTask and dismiss progress in PostExecute method

Comment: yes Instead of Thread use AsyncTask. see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Progress dialog spin first 2-3 seconds and then stuck.

Because parsing of json response and `downloadConsumerData` method making api request from main UI Thread.

In `Volley` `onResponse` method called as callback method on main UI Thread when network request is completed.

For parsing request response in `onResponse` method use `AsyncTask` class and call `ProgressDialog` dismiss method in `onPostExecute` method which will close `ProgressDialog` when Volley request, parsing of json data and `downloadConsumerData` method job is done in background Thread

Start AsyncTask from `onResponse` method :

```
  @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(response);
  }
```

In `doInBackground` process JSON data:

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
         totalConsumerRecords = Integer.parseInt(response.getString
                           ("TotalConsumerRecords").trim());
        // add all code here from onResponse
        downloadSupplyTownData(townId);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I have also searched, I have found AsyncTask does not effective in case of volley.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee:  You are Right!. read my answer. i am saying use `AsyncTask` for process data which you have received from Volley lib response. I this way application make server request using Volley lib but after receiving response application process it on other thread using doInBackground instead of UI Thread as currently you are doing in `onResponse`

Comment: How can I place only response part within AsyncTask. I am totally hangout.

Comment: Many many thanks, Solved. It's very much needed for all volley users. I have accepted and + up you answer.