# progress dialog keeps on spinning even after inserting data

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I am just creating a simple signup module. I have written the following code it inserts data but the progress dialog keeps on spinning and it never stops but if I check my database the data is there inserted correctly. I am using volley framework. I am a beginner on Android volley please tell me where I am going wrong.

**registration.java**

```
public class registration extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText Name,Email,Username,Password;
ProgressDialog dialog;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String Reg_url="------";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
    Name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    Email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    Username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
    Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait a Momment");

    dialog.setCancelable(false);
}
public void SignUp(View view)
{
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name.getText().toString()))
    {
        Name.setError("At least 5 charachters");
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Email.getText().toString()))
    {
        Email.setError("Enter a Valid Email");
    }
   else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Username.getText().toString()))
    {
        Username.setError("At least 5 charachters");
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Password.getText().toString()))
    {
        Password.setError("At least 5 charachters");
    }
    else
    {
        dialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Reg_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(registration.this,MainActivity.class));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(registration.this,"Connection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("name",Name.getText().toString());
                map.put("email",Email.getText().toString());
                map.put("user_name",Username.getText().toString());
                map.put("password",Password.getText().toString());

                return map;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeout= 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
}
```

I have added user permission for internet in the manifest file.
I have volley framework dependency volley 1.1.0.
It shows the onerrorresponse correctly but in response if i apply a toast that won't show either but data is inserted.

My php code is:

```
<?php
require "connect.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email =$_POST["email"];
$user_name =$_POST["user_name"];
$password =$_POST["password"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`name`, `email`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$user_name','$password')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I believe your code is ending up in `catch (JSONException e)` block. Put the `dialog.dismiss();` in the catch block as well & see. Not an expert of php, but your PHP code doesn't seems to return valid json response back so the android code at `JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);` is failing & going in catch block

Comment: yes that seems to be the problem it stops can you help correct my functionality

Comment: you doesn't seems to be using the `jsonArray` or `jsonObject` so just comment out the whole try catch block & just have 
`dialog.dismiss();
                            startActivity(new Intent(registration.this,MainActivity.class));
finish();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley ProgressDialog stuck/freeze at the time of get huge amount of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978274/volley-progressdialog-stuck-freeze-at-the-time-of-get-huge-amount-of-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your response block like this

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(registration.this,"Response :"+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(registration.this,MainActivity.class));                                                                                
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

EDIT : *`Configure your php code in such a way that it returns a response during a network call. And then parse the response in the app side. Currently your try block is not getting executed due to no response from backend(even if the backend query is executed)`*

PHP code

```
    <?php
require "connect.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email =$_POST["email"];
$user_name =$_POST["user_name"];
$password =$_POST["password"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`name`, `email`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$user_name','$password')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$myArray = array();
if($result){
$myArray = array("status" => "success", 'code' => "200")
} else{
$myArray = array("status" => "failure", 'code' => "400")
}
echo json_encode($myArray);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167493/discussion-on-answer-by-navneet--progress-dialog-keeps-on-spining-even-after-in).

Comment: @BhargavRao thanks for notifying, will consider this from now on

Answer (score 0):

Your try/catch block is likely failing. Test to make sure this is the case by a) setting a breakpoint on the try/catch block and running it line by line through the debugger until you find which line is causing the error to be thrown, or b) adding a log statement to the catch block that includes e.getLocalizedMessage() so you can see the error output, or c) just putting dialog.dismiss() in the catch black and see if it goes away. If you get the error message and don't know what it means post it and we'll get to the bottom of it.

Comment: puting dialog.dismss() in catch makes it goes away thats done but my end code is not working that is finishing this activity and moving to the next

Comment: Your code is failing at either JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response); or JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); Likely the latter. Use the debugger to go in and see what line it is failing at and share the error output from the log in android monitor. Let's see what it says.

Comment: when i debug it says unable to debug because of an intent-filter

Comment: Are you still calling startActivity() before the try/catch? You should call that last.

Comment: i have returened the origional that i posted

Comment: print e.getLocalizedMessage in the catch block, What does that say?

Comment: thats what i thought i should do but doing what @Navneet recomended made my problem go away and now reading all the discussion i wanted to see that if it solves like this

Comment: Navneet's answer works if you don't need to capture a response from the server before you move on to the next activity. If you just want to fire off a message and don't care whether or not it makes it or is successful than maybe that is the right answer for your application, however, this is rarely the case in real life.

Comment: i debugged it from under RUN debug Alt+Shift+F9 and now it won't run the app

Comment: yeah i want a response that it was succesfull or not

Comment: i started it but i hade dialog.dismiss() in catch it dismissed dialog but nothing else

Comment: should i echo out something from my php script

Comment: i am getting nothing i am blank as to i don't know what to do and how to do

Comment: i am debugging it whatever i do on my app the log goes one step ahead but doesnot give me an error even when my app is stuck at dialog

Comment: it gives response=" " as i applied a break at the whole onresponse part

Comment: the localizeMessage say" org.json.JSONException:end of an input at charachter 0 of"